# A Filter function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

My Tree definition is as follows:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)
```

I want to write a filter function that picks only every 3rd element of an array (1st, 4th, 7th, ...). As an example, suppose my tree is as follows:

```
Node 
    (Node 
        (Node 
            (Leaf 'a') 
            (Leaf 'b')) 
        (Leaf 'c'))
    (Node 
        (Node 
            (Leaf 'd') 
            (Leaf 'e')) 
        (Leaf 'f'))
```

Then the filter function should result in a new tree as:

```
Node (Leaf 'a') (Leaf 'd')
```

Comment: What if your tree has 7+ elements...what would the resulting tree look like?

Comment: This isn't really a sufficient specification of how the tree filter operation would look like. What if the tree has, say, 9 elements? What will be the shape of the resulting tree?

Comment: If the tree has 9 elements, it will pick 1st, 4th, 7th element. It picks 1st, 4th, 7th, 10th, 13th, 16th, ...

Comment: Yes, but how would the resulting structure look?  How would it be nested?

Comment: by modifying this filter function should be somehow balanced:   filterTree p (Leaf a) | p a = Just (Leaf a) | otherwise = Nothing filterTree p (Node l r) = case ( filterTree p l, filterTree p r) of (Nothing, r) -> r (l, Nothing) -> l (Just l, Just r) -> Just (Node l r)

Comment: There is no preference for how it is nested, but preferably balanced.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a gameplan for you.

1. Write a function that applies a function to each element of your tree.

   ```
   mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
   ```

   (Bonus: make `Tree` a `Functor` instance, and use `fmap` instead of `mapTree`)
2. Write a function that labels the elements of a tree in order of their left-to-right occurrence.

   ```
   labelTree :: Tree a -> Tree (Integer, a)
   ```

   (Hint: you will need an auxiliary function which takes a "current label" and returns the labeled tree together with a new label; i.e. `:: Integer -> Tree a -> (Tree (Integer, a), Integer)`. The branch case of this function goes like this:

   ```
   aux n (Branch l r) = 
       let (l', n')  = aux n l
           (r', n'') = aux n' r in
       (Branch l' r', n'')
   ```

   Carefully read this code, and then see if you can come up with the `Leaf` case)

   (Bonus: do it using the [`State` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html))
3. Write a function which removes the elements of a tree which do not satisfy a condition.

   ```
   filterTree :: (a -> Bool) -> Tree a -> Maybe (Tree a)
   ```

   Notice that we return a `Maybe (Tree a)` rather than just a `Tree a` -- this is because we need to have something to return if no elements match the condition, and your `Tree` type does not permit empty trees.  It so happens that returning a `Maybe (Tree a)` also makes this function quite straightforward to write recursively.
4. Combine these functions to get the function you are looking for -- filtering out only the elements with labels that are divisible by 3.

The nice thing about decomposing it this way is that, in addition to solving your specific problem, you have written yourself a number of generally useful tools for working with your `Tree` type.  Maps and filters are very common functions that appear when implementing a data structures.

*Advanced:* the `State` monad bonus implementation of `labelTree` is a specific case of another common type of function called a  ["traversal"](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Traversable.html):

```
traverse :: (Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> Tree a -> f (Tree b)
```

which is like a map but also combines the "effects" that can occur on each element.  Super double-plus bonus if you can implement it and then use it to write `labelTree`.

Comment: In this way, we are defining a new type tree with label. But there is a approach which we can modify this filter function:          filterTree p (Leaf a)  
                       | p a = Just (Leaf a)  
                       | otherwise = Nothing
                       

filterTree p (Node l r) = case ( filterTree p l, filterTree p r) of
                                (Nothing, r) -> r
                                (l, Nothing) -> l
                                (Just l, Just r) -> Just (Node l r)

Comment: The label tracking is possible by counting the number of leaves on the left side of each node.

Comment: @user2476499, do you know how to write a recursive function?  Counting the number of leaves in a tree is about the simplest recursive function there is, maybe start with that.

Comment: i can do that, but that does not help here, i am not talking about size of a tree, what i said means i need to pass the number of leaves which resides on the left side of a node in the tree structure.

Comment: @user2476499, Oh, you're right, the size doesn't help. I had a braino.  The trick is in the auxiliary function I mentioned.  I edited the question and added a hint about it.  In particular, look at how `n`, `n'`, and `n''` are related.

Comment: Is this correct?:                                                  aux n (Leaf a) = (Leaf (a, n), n+1)